# How do I tell CSS to recalculate :first-of-type after DOM dynamically changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following CSS rules:

```
        .block:first-of-type{
            border-top: 1px solid black;
        }

        .block:last-of-type{
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
```

This `.block` div is generated via AJAX and can be added multiple times to the page. The problem is that every time I add one of them, *all* divs are read as both first and last of the document. I assume it is because the CSS doesn't recognize the changes that happen in the DOM. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> all divs are read as both first and last of the document

You misunderstand what `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` mean.

See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo)

> Same as :nth-of-type(1). The :first-of-type pseudo-class represents an element that is the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.

The important bit is *children of its parent element* **not** *document*.

You can see it does that quite correctly here:

```js
function middle() {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("inserted in middle"));
  var p = document.querySelector("div + div + div");
  p.parentNode.insertBefore(d, p);
}

function first() {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("inserted at top"));
  var p = document.querySelector("div");
  p.parentNode.insertBefore(d, p);
}

setTimeout(middle, 2000);
setTimeout(first, 4000);
```

```css
div:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
div:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>Original First</div>
<div>Original Second</div>
<div>Original Third</div>
<div>Original Fourth</div>
<div>Original Fifth</div>
```

You are, presumably creating a structure such as:

```
<div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

… in which every div of that class is the first div in its parent element.

Given that layout then you would need something more akin to `:first-of-type > .block` as your selector.

The precise nature of the selector you need would depend on the DOM you are creating, but you haven't shared that with us.

Comment: I found a solution, actually it was a bit more complicated but your input solved the initial part of the problem.